# Can't bind to local 5037 for debugger (again)

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I'm getting this when I try to debug my Android app on a new Eclipse ADB bundle installation downloaded about 10 days ago. It's running on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. Debugging was working fine for a while, then suddenly started giving me these errors.

Having read through other threads I've tried the following:
- Stopped and restarted Eclipse and the emulator multiple times
- Added 127.0.0.1 localhost to my hosts file
- Set base local debugger port in DDMS to 8601, ticked "Use ADB Host" and set an ADB host value of 127.0.0.1
- Killed and restarted ADB from the command line (adb kill-server followed by adb start-server)
- Killed adb.exe from Task Manager and restarted Eclipse
- Uninstalled Java 7 update 51 - now I just have Java 6 (updates 34 & 38) and Java 8 (update 5) - all 64-bit
- Disabled AVG anti-virus (the Windows firewall was already disabled)

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I'm in the same boat except with IntelliJ (tried all those things), although I must be very clear that this is only when DDMS is started. If I close it I can launch a debug session fine from within IntelliJ.  I've noticed I get this every time in my Console tab of DDMS when I try to launch: "[2014-10-29 15:01:22 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe